# Show a div as a tootip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I need to figure out some JQuery code that enables a div to show up as a tooltip, and I don't want to use any plugin from JQuery UI.

The requirements are:

1. that div should follow the cursor
2. When the cursor hovers over the div, "tootip" should remain visible.

I just need the basic idea of how to do it. I have succeeded in showing a div as a tool tip but it disappears when the cursor gets out from anchor tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {

        var mouseX;
        var mouseY;
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            mouseX = e.pageX;
            mouseY = e.pageY;
        });

        jQuery('.trigger').mouseenter(function() {



            var width = parseInt(jQuery('#pop-up').css('width'), 10);

            jQuery('#pop-up').css('top', mouseY);
            jQuery('#pop-up').css('left', mouseX - width);
            jQuery('#pop-up').fadeIn(500);


        }).mouseleave(function() {
            jQuery('#pop-up').fadeOut();
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: and the question is ??? and where is your codes ??

Comment: [Google!](https://www.google.nl/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+tooltip)

Comment: Why to use JQuery or a plugin like http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Comment: Please review updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var changeTooltipPosition = function (event) {
    var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
    var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
    $('div.tooltip').css({
        top: tooltipY,
        left: tooltipX
    });
};

var showTooltip = function (event) {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
    $('<div class="tooltip">Div should follow the cursor! :)</div>')
        .appendTo('body');
    changeTooltipPosition(event);
};

var hideTooltip = function () {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
};

$("span#hint,label#username").bind({
    mousemove: changeTooltipPosition,
    mouseenter: showTooltip,
    mouseleave: hideTooltip
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smxc/)  *(Reference: [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-create-a-tooltips-with-jquery/))*